# Convert a String to a String[], splitted by characters in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, type-conversion

I want to convert a whole `string` to a `string[]` splitted by characters.

Example:

```
myText = "text text text"
```

transforming into

```
myStringArray[0] = {"t"};
myStringArray[1] = {"e"};
myStringArray[2] = {"x"};
myStringArray[3] = {"t"};
myStringArray[4] = {" "};
...
```

Comment: Have you checked with `myText .ToCharArray();`

Comment: the method `ToCharArray` will convert my `string` into a `char`. I need to work with the data type `string`

Comment: I read the other question "How to convert string to string[]?", but I need splitted, not the whole text in one 'space' of an array

Comment: Did you checked the link? there you can find the solution for your problem. there is an answer by `Sayed Abolfazl Fatemi`